# handling incoming whatsapp calls programmatically

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, whatsapi

I am interested in handling incoming video or voice calls on WhatsApp programmatically, using languages such as NodeJS, PHP, or Java. I have searched online but only found information about handling phone voice calls using Twilio service or other services. I want to know if it's possible to:

1. Receive incoming WhatsApp calls
2. Answer the call
3. Receive streaming data and send data back simultaneously in a bidirectional connection
4. End the call.

I would appreciate any help in achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio supports messaging using WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp), but there's no support for making voice calls. I don't think WhatsApp provides APIs to do this either.

You can build the solution you're suggesting with [Twilio Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice), but that would be using phone calling over the telephone network, not over WhatsApp.